# Explain the reason for this behaviour of mockito matches(str) vs same(str)

Tags: java, junit, mockito, matcher

This might be a question to the Mockito developers that might end up as a bug see the **"Update"** at the bottom.

---

The following code

test_0 - PASS -- as expected

test_1 - **FAIL -- WHY?? <-- this is something I do not understand.**

test_2 - PASS -- as expected

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.matches;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.same;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Test_mockito_strange {

    public static class A {
        protected B b = new B();

        public B read(String s) {
            return b;
        }
    }

    public static class B {
        String[] getData() {
            return new String[] {
                    "aa"
            };
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test_0() {

        assertTrue(Pattern.matches("00", "00"));
        assertTrue(Pattern.matches("11", "11"));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_1()
    {
        A a = mock(A.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        String[] m1 = new String[] {"bb"}; 
        String[] m2 = new String[] {"cc"};
        String[] m3 = new String[] {"dd"};

        when(a.read(anyString()).getData()).thenReturn(m1);
        when(a.read(matches("00")).getData()).thenReturn(m2);
        when(a.read(matches("11")).getData()).thenReturn(m3);

        assertTrue("cc".equals(a.read("00").getData()[0]));
        assertTrue("dd".equals(a.read("11").getData()[0]));
        assertTrue("bb".equals(a.read("33").getData()[0]));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_2()
    {
        A a = mock(A.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        String[] m1 = new String[] {"bb"}; 
        String[] m2 = new String[] {"cc"};
        String[] m3 = new String[] {"dd"};

        when(a.read(anyString()).getData()).thenReturn(m1);
        when(a.read(same("00")).getData()).thenReturn(m2);
        when(a.read(same("11")).getData()).thenReturn(m3);

        assertTrue("cc".equals(a.read("00").getData()[0]));
        assertTrue("dd".equals(a.read("11").getData()[0]));
        assertTrue("bb".equals(a.read("33").getData()[0]));
    }
}
```

in pom.xml i got

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

using jdk8 on Windows 10. Eclipse 4.9.

**Update:**

---

While debugging I have noticed that: 
Both ***matches(...)*** and ***same(...)*** end up as instances of the ***org.mockito.internal.matchers.Matches.class*** and ***org.mockito.internal.matchers.Same.class*** respectively

Both implement ***org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher*** interface

But for some reason during the execution ***Same.matches(Object actual)*** method is called while the ***Matchers.matches(Object actual)*** is never called

Please can someone point out what do I miss?

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with overlapping matchers. If you try without

```
when(a.read(anyString()).getData()).thenReturn(m1)
```

test_1() will pass.

Comment: notice that it works well with the same() 

and the whole point is that I need that is that

in case 1 => return A

incase 2 => return B

all other cases => return C